# How to open new form when Enter as Tab?

Tags: c#, winforms, keypress, keydown

When I Press `Enter` button, it acts as `Tab` with this code at `form1_keydown` event

```
 Control nextControl; 
 if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
 {
 nextControl = GetNextControl(ActiveControl, !e.Shift);
 nextControl.Focus();
 e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
 }
```

There is `comboBox`in a form to which we press `Enter` button then open `New Form`.
How to do it because it doesn't work on `cmb_KeyPress`event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here You can wirte as:

```
 Control nextControl; 
 if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
 {
nextControl = GetNextControl(ActiveControl, !e.Shift);
nextControl.Focus();
if(nextControl=Combo)
{
KeyPreview=false;   
}
e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
}
```